# Numeric categorical variables as factors or one hot encoded before using random forest?

Tags: random-forest, categorical-encoding, caret

I am performing a random forest model in R using caret = rf method. I have 20 explanatory variables and most are continuous but a few are categorical and numeric. For example, there are 6 categories of soil drainage coded as 1-6 class = integer. Before running the model I converted these categorical variables to factors using as.factor().

```r
df1000 <- transform(df1000, LU1945=as.factor(LU1945), 
             LU1960=as.factor(LU1960), HSG=as.factor(HSG),  
              Drainage=as.factor(Drainage))
```

Should this type of variable (nominal categorical) be one-hot encoded instead?

Comment: You should [edit] to specify which random forest implementation you are using, and in which language because different implementations work differently. Caret (presumably in R) implements multiple random forests.

Comment: Isn't converting to a factor just the way of telling the model to do one-hot encoding internally? Maybe `caret` has its own rules...

Comment: That is what I assumed too, Dave. But my variable importance table lists each factor level for the categorical variable so I began to wonder if as.factor() has the same effect as one hot encoding? Also, when I do not convert to factor ideal hyperparameter values change when tuning so I am worried.

Comment: I suspect that is because one-hot encoding yourself tells the model that you have multiple features, while passing the variable as a factor passes the variable as an entire chunk.